# Invalid Syntax error in Python Code I copied from the Internet to read hyperspectral image

Tags: python, image-processing

this is the part of code that I copied in my program. my python is version 3.6. and used Ipython console to run it. but there is this error that I can't understand. could you please help me?

```
from spectral import *
img = open_image('92AV3C.lan')
print(img)
img.__class__
DataSource: 'D:/somayeh- work docs/test program with python/92AV3C.lan'
    # Rows:            145
    # Samples:         145
    # Bands:           220
Interleave:        BIL
Quantization:   16 bits
Data format:     int16

img.shape(145, 145, 220)
pixel = img[50,100]

pixel.shape(220,)

band6 = img[:,:,5]

band6.shape(145, 145, 1)
```

---

error : Quantization:   16 bit
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It's a `SyntaxError`... The syntax is not correct. Read more about python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html)

Comment: The code includes the output of the `print()` call, by the looks of it. It's not formatted for easy copying.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be reading [this page of the Spectral Python documentation](http://www.spectralpython.net/fileio.html).

They are showing an *interactive Python session*, including output of the commands entered. You copied the *print result*, there to be part of a demo.

The printed output is not Python syntax. Stick to the lines starting with `In [<digit>]:`.

For the first and second examples, together:

```
In [1]: from spectral import *

In [2]: img = open_image('92AV3C.lan')

In [3]: img.__class__
Out[3]: spectral.io.bilfile.BilFile

In [4]: print img
    Data Source:   '/home/thomas/spectral_data/92AV3C.lan'
    # Rows:            145
    # Samples:         145
    # Bands:           220
    Interleave:        BIL
    Quantization:  16 bits
    Data format:     int16

In [5]: img.shape
Out[5]: (145, 145, 220)

In [6]: pixel = img[50,100]

In [7]: pixel.shape
Out[7]: (220,)

In [8]: band6 = img[:,:,5]

In [9]: band6.shape
Out[9]: (145, 145, 1)
```

adjusted for Python 3, the code executed is

```
from spectral import *
img = open_image('92AV3C.lan')
img.__class__
print(img)
img.shape
pixel = img[50,100]
pixel.shape
band6 = img[:,:,5]
band6.shape
```

Most of this is just producing extra output aimed at helping you to understand what kind of objects are being produced and how they model data.